# Cant add/restore Fragment sameclass at Backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using one activity to handle multiple items details.

`ActivityA` has a product list and when you click in any item at this list, you call `ActivityB` passing the product ID:

`ActivityA`:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(this, ProductDetail.class);
    i.putExtra("pID", product.getId());
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
```

At the `onCreate` and `onNewIntent` methods,I handle it in this way:

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); //bundle to send data to the fragment
        bundle.putInt("pID", intent.getExtras().getInt("pID"));
        ProductDetail details = new ProductDetail();
        details.setArguments(bundle);
        loadFragment(details);
    }
```

And the `loadFragment` that must add or return to a specific Fragment if it finds one with the same pID tag:

```
public void loadFragment(ProductDetail fragment) {
        fm = getFragmentManager();
        Log.d("TagFrag", "TAG: "+ pID); //can get pID from global variable or extra from fragment
        if(fm.findFragmentByTag(pID+"") !=null) {
            Log.d("TagFrag", "Already Added");
            fm.popBackStack(pID+ "", 0);

        } else {

            Log.d("TagFrag", "New Added");
            ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.fragments, fragment, pID+ "");
            ft.commit();
            fm.executePendingTransactions();

        }
```

It shows if it's a `"New Added"` or `"Already Added"`, but the                 `fm.popBackStack(pID+ "", 0);` shows only the last added fragment.

ex:

> Click Item 1 -> addFragment -> Display Item 1 Details
>
> Click Item 2 -> addFragment -> Display Item 2 Details

If I return to the Item list and click the Item1 again the behavior is:

> Click Item **1** -> fragmentAlreadyAdded -> Display Item **2** Details
>   Why is it not displaying item 1 again?

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually add something to backstack? Check `fm.getBackStackEntryCount()`. If 0 then you need to add transactions: `ft.addToBackStack(tag)`

Comment: its adding to the backStage, entryCount is counting, the problem is that when i use the popBack to return to the first fragment, all the others are destroyed, i dont want this =/

Comment: @user2582318 From your source isn't obvious that addToBackStack is called at all. Anyway did you consider using of show/hide methods of FragmentTransaction?

Comment: sorry i forgot to add, and i didnt consider, is there anyway to store the Fragment without loosing data and then show/hide?